# Managed Email Template is not showing on Lookup

Tags: email-template

I created a lightning component that contains a field that looks up an email template.
This is the attributes from the component:

```
<aura:attribute name="emailTmp" type="EmailTemplate" default="{'sobjectType':'EmailTemplate', 'id':null}"/>
<aura:attribute name="emailTmpFields" type="EmailTemplate" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'EmailTemplate', 'Name': ''}"/>
```

I am using the lookupInput sample by [Enrico Murru](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html) to create the lookup:

```
<div ><c:lookupInput type="{!v.emailTmp.sobjectType}" value="{!v.emailTmpFields.Name}" className="slds-input " /></div>
```

it worked in the developer org and I created a patch for it. but when I installed the patch to a new org, the lookup only gets the unmanaged email templates. so when I was looking up on a managed template, nothing shows in the list. What might have happened here?

Comment: Are they paid managed package, if yes then check the license.

Comment: @TusharSharma yes the're paid. you mean the salesforce liscense? I checked it and it is 100% used up. Does this causes the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your user doesn't have a license you won't be able to view them. To access paid manage package component we need license access.

So assign your user a license to view the email templates.